# C# Dictionary to .csv

Tags: c#, file, csv

I have C# `Dictionary` and I want create a `.csv` file from it.
For example I have this dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, string> data = new Dictionary<string, string>();
data.Add("0", "0.15646E3");
data.Add("1", "0.45655E2");
data.Add("2", "0.46466E1");
data.Add("3", "0.45615E0");
```

And I wanna this `.csv` file output:

```
0;0.15646E3;
1;0.45655E2;
2;0.46466E1;
3;0.45615E0;
```

How can I do this?

Comment: CSV stands for "comma separated values".  What you have there is semicolon separated values (which is fine, it's just not CSV).

Comment: @Servy I know it's stupid but in France CSV is separated by ; so it's not really an error from the author

Comment: @Guillaume86 There are many dilimiters used in text files, commas are common, but others use tabs, spaces, pipes ('|'), semi colons, dashes, apostrophes, and I'm sure others.  They are all text delimited files, but they are not all CSV files, only comma delimited text files are.  There's nothing wrong with a semi colon as a delimiter.

Comment: @Servy: Read the "Lack of standard" section of the wikipedia article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values in france and some other contries they use the decimal point as a comma instead of period, so even "CSV" files are not separated by comas (localized version of MS Excel will use ';' as separator when you save as csv for exemple).

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Maybe the easiest:

```
String csv = String.Join(
    Environment.NewLine,
    data.Select(d => $"{d.Key};{d.Value};")
);
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(pathToCsv, csv);
```

You'll need to add `using LINQ` and use at least .NET 3.5

Comment: This solution will write the key and the value in the same cell

Answer (score 11):

Try the following

```
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(@"the\path\to\my.csv")) {
  foreach (var pair in data) {
    writer.WriteLine("{0};{1};", pair.Key, pair.Value);
  }
}
```

Note: This will fail to work if the key or value elements can contain a `;`.  If so you will need to add an escaping mechanism to handle that

Comment: This will add the key and the value in the same cell, change the ; to , like this writer.WriteLine("{0},{1},", pair.Key, pair.Value);

Answer (score 8):

```
  File.WriteAllLines(@"pathtocsv.csv", data.Select(x => x.Key + ";" + x.Value + ";")));
```

Answer (score 0):

My dictionary was similar to the one in the question posed above (by user1387150) except the VALUE part was an array (of doubles, i.e.double[]).

Adjusting Jared's solution above, allows a `Dictionary<string, double[]>` to be written to csv as follows:

```
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\path\test.csv"))
    {
        foreach (var pair in data)
        {
            writer.WriteLine("{0},{1};", pair.Key, String.Join(",", pair.Value.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray()));
        }
    }
```