# Serialize object with dictionary property to .csv

Tags: c#, csv, .net-core, serialization

I would like to serialize an object containing a dictionary into a csv.
The csv would be a template for user with given properties to process

```
Class A
{
    string Id;
    IDictionary<string, string> PropertiesTobeUpdated; 
}
```

User can ask to update:
property1: value1
..
propertyN: valueN

Any idea a about a good type Converter for dictionary in c# that still user friendly for csv serializer?

Thanks.

Comment: You're unlikely to find an existing library which performs your custom logic, and library recommendations are off-topic here either way.  Instead, you are encouraged to attempt to build your functionality.  If you encounter a specific technical problem during that attempt, such as an error or unexpected result, we can help with that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# Dictionary to .csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10538425/c-sharp-dictionary-to-csv)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is to implement ClassMap with appropriate converter for dictionaries:

```
public sealed class SomeClass: ClassMap<T>
{
    public SomeClass()
    {
        AutoMap(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        Map(m => m.PropertiesTobeUpdated).TypeConverter<DictionnaryConverter();
    }
}

public class DictionnaryConverter : DefaultTypeConverter
{
    public override object ConvertFromString(string text, IReaderRow row, MemberMapData memberMapData)
    {
        // ***
    }

    public override string ConvertToString(object value, IWriterRow row, MemberMapData memberMapData)
    {
        // ***
    }
}
```